# How manager My models with mongoose node.js and express?

Tags: node.js

I've a problem for organize my models.
first I get this error:

```
User is not defined
```

and when I include in routes.js my model, like this:

```
var User = require('../models/user');
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot overwrite User model once compiled.
```

[There is](https://github.com/Sampistaroy/pb-once-exist) my repot corresponding to my first error.

ty for your assist.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first issue, when you want to retrieve your model its better to use [Mongoose#model](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-model). For example

For example:

```
require('../models/user');

var mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    User = mongoose.model("User");

User.find({ // ...now you can use the User model
```

Regarding your second issue, you only have to require user.js once to compile your model. When you include it in route.js, it's being loaded twice in your app (app.js requires it too, looking at your repo).

If you're not sure how to organise your models, use other Express/Mongoose apps as a starting point. I've used [this repo](https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo) in the past. Relevant instance of organising and compiling your models are in server.js and /app/models